# Part to pierce the valve on a 16g CO2 cartridge and connect to a Solenoid valve

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure, gas, valves, connections

The specific part that I’m after is something that can connect to a solenoid valve and a CO2 cartridge that will break the seal on the end of the CO2 cartridge.

The solenoid valve connection is roughly *1/2*”/*12mm* (female, threaded)
which is just about the same as for the CO2 cartridge as shown below *3/8"*/*9mm* (male, threaded).

I want to be able to control the flow of CO2 using an electric current. Does anyone know the name of the part that I would need and where to get one? Thanks in advance :)

[image: Gas cartridge]